# Grouping in Crystal Reports crosstab

Tags: crystal-reports, report, reporting, grouping, crystal-reports-xi

I'm using Crystal Reports XI R2 and want to build a table using crosstab functionality to display some data. The trouble is I don't want grouping on rows, eg. I want all rows (except the period) to be displayed underneath each other and not one row be a subgroup of another) I want it to look like this:

```
Period 1
       Group 1  value 1 | Summary field
       Group 1  value 2 | Summary field
       Group 1  value 3 | Summary field
       Group 2  value 1 | Summary field
       Group 2  value 2 | Summary field
       Group 3  value 1 | Summary field
       Group 3  value 2 | Summary field
       Group 3  value 3 | Summary field

Period 2
       Group 1  value 1 | Summary field
       Group 1  value 2 | Summary field
       Group 1  value 3 | Summary field

...
```

Instead of this:

```
Period 1
       Group 1 value 1 | Group 2 value 1 | Group 3 value 1 | Summary field 
                                         | Group 3 value 2 | Summary field 
                                         | Group 3 value 3 | Summary field 
                       | Group 2 value 2 | Group 3 value 1 | Summary field 
                                         | Group 3 value 2 | Summary field 
                                         | Group 3 value 3 | Summary field 

       Group 1 value 2 | Group 2 value 1 | Group 3 value 1 | Summary field 
                                         | Group 3 value 2 | Summary field 
                                         | Group 3 value 3 | Summary field 
                       | Group 2 value 2 | Group 3 value 1 | Summary field 
                                         | Group 3 value 2 | Summary field 

                                         | Group 3 value 3 | Summary field 
Period 2
       Group 1 value 1 | Group 2 value 1 | Group 3 value 1 | Summary field 
                                         | Group 3 value 2 | Summary field 
                                         | Group 3 value 3 | Summary field 

...
```

I want to group my data on Group 1 Field only (period, selected by the user, so it can by grouped by days, weeks, months, years - I already have a formula to work it out). The other fields are:

- Group 2 (Flight Service Type, eg. Scheduled, charter, transfer etc.),
- Group 3 (Airport Group Type, eg: Schengen/Non-Schengen, Continents,
  GCC/Non-GCC etc - those are defined by the user)
- Group 4 (Flight direction - either Departure or Arrival).

As you can see, those three groups are not related to each other and each Flight belongs to  ALL 3 of those groups (Eg. Flight A is Scheduled (group 2), Schengen (group 3) and Arrival (group 4)), and that's where I think the problem is.

Can this be achieved in Crystal Reports XI R2 using cross tabs?

Comment: Why not use 'regular' grouping (i.e. sections and group fields)?

Comment: I tried that as well, but it gives me exactly the same results (apart from the styling).

Comment: Would you mind listing the names of the fields that you are using for grouping?  The two examples have multiple interpretations.

Comment: Thx, I've just added further explanations together with group names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because these things aren't related you will need to move flight service, airport group, and flight direction to individual sub-reports (one for each).  Place each sub-report in a separate GH1 section (i.e. GH1b, GH1c, GH1d)--GH1a will contain the group name and summary field.

You'll group the data in each sub-report as desired.

You can link the main report to each sub-report if you want to correlate the data.

Comment: Is it possible to run the Command which will retrieve all the data needed from the main report and then pass this data to individual sub-reports? Or do I need to write SQL commands in each of the subreports to get the data that is needed in there?

Comment: Each sub-report will need its own query (generated by the Database 'Expert' or from a SQL command).  Passing database between main and sub-reports is limited.

Comment: Thanks, just tried to put one group into subreport and it looks like it's working. I tried to avoid adding each group into its own subreport because I'm going to run some calculations on data from each group so it's going to make it more complicated, but it looks like it's the only way to go... Thanks for your help!

Comment: One more question. Putting each sub report into its own GH section should display the table correctly with data grouped according to the period. However, I'm also required to display charts for each group, and this could not be displayed in the subsection as it will create one chart for each period (and I want only one). Any suggestion on how this could be solved?

Comment: If I understand what you are asking, then you will need to add a sub-report to the Report Header section (so it is only generated once).  The sub-report would need to do the hard work to generate the aggregates--perhaps a UNION in a Command.

Comment: Would then I have just one subreport (for 3 group types) or one for each?